# How to handle Salesforce Standard Application Events (not custom created) in Aura?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, event

In the chatter publisher, there is a Upcoming and Overdue tasks section in which a checkbox is shown in front of task, when I check it the task status will change to Completed.

I need to do some steps after I click on that checkbox, Since it is Salesforce out-of-the-box functionality I tried seeing what happens when checkbox is checked using Lightning Inspector Extension, I found one Event being fired:

```
function(a,b,c,d,e) {
   var f =  $A.getEvt("markup://runtime_sales_activities:taskStatusChange");
   f.setParams({ 

     // some params
)}

f.fire()
}
```

I tried adding a aura:handler in an aura component which is in same flexipage as chatter publisher for this event.

Tried following ways but unable to deploy:

1.

```
<aura:handler event="runtime_sales_activities:taskStatusChange" action="{!c.someMethd}">
```

Error while deploying -> NO EVENT named runtime_sales_activities:taskStatusChange found

2.

```
<aura:handler event="c:taskStatusChange" action="{!c.someMethd}">
```

Error while deploying -> NO EVENT named markup://c:taskStatusChange found.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce Standard Application Events are built-in events that can be fired by the platform or by other Lightning components. To handle these events in an Aura component, you need to define a handler for the event in the component's controller.

Here's an example of how to handle the force:navigateToSObject event, which is a standard event that is fired when a user clicks on a link to a Salesforce record:

<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />

Define a handler function for the force:navigateToSObject event. This function will be called when the event is fired:

```
handleNavigateToSObject : function(component, event, helper) {
// Get the Id of the record that was clicked
var recordId = event.getParam("recordId");
// Set the record Id attribute in the component
component.set("v.recordId", recordId);
```

Register the handler function for the force:navigateToSObject event in your component:

```
<aura:handler event="force:navigateToSObject" action="{!c.handleNavigateToSObject}" />
```

Now, when the force:navigateToSObject event is fired, the handleNavigateToSObject function will be called, and the Id of the clicked record will be stored in the recordId attribute of the component.

You can handle other standard events in a similar way, by defining a handler function for the event and registering the function as a handler in the component. The names of the standard events and the parameters they provide are documented in the Salesforce Lightning Component Library.